# How to include audio and picture into .exe ( Visual Studio )

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does anyone know how can I include a picture and a .wav file into my .exe file? ( C++ )
If i run the build `PlaySound(TEXT("Audio.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);` it will work well, but if a another person opens the .exe where the .wav file is not in the same direction the sound won`t play, how can i include the audio into the .exe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference: Please tag your question with only one language tag at a time. I came here from the (irrelevant) C# tag and can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you could try to add the files to your project as resources, then you could try to use [PlaySound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/playing-wave-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to use them.

I suggest you could refer to the thread:[PlaySound works in Visual Studio but not in standalone exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424691/playsound-works-in-visual-studio-but-not-in-standalone-exe)

Comment: Yes, I added the .wav file to my project as a ressource, but it isn't included in the .exe, so the .wav file must be in the same directory to work.

Comment: @ThomasBecker Instead of adding it to the project reference, you add the embed code to .rc file, for example icon: `IDI_SMALL ICON "small.ico"`, you should add your line as: `IDI_WAV 256 "your.wav"`.